# SwiftyJSON Property Trouble

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am working with SwiftyJSON which is great.  I am however having an issue with storing the JSON(data:) result in a property in my viewController.  The standard use of SwiftyJSON works fine.

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
let name = json[1]["name"].string
```

My problem occurs when I try to create a property to store the result of JSON(data:)

```
// Property    
var jsonData : JSON?

    someMethod()
    {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        self.jsonData = json
        if let name = self.jsonData[1]["name"].string
        {
              print(name)
        }
    }
```

When I do this I get an error on the following line.

```
 if let name = self.jsonData[1]["name"].string
```

> Cannot find member 'string'

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I am not sure why this was marked down.  If you mark it down please let me know why so I can make better posts in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an optional property.

var jsonData : JSON?

just use

```
if let name = self.jsonData?[1]["name"].string
```

in place of

```
if let name = self.jsonData[1]["name"].string
```

in your case complier trying to find a property which can be  a nil.